# How to encrypt response body from nestJS interceptor?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, interceptor

I am not able to get Body in interceptor.
This is from one of the controller.

masterData.controller.ts

```
const data = await this.masterDataService.fetchWorkExperienceData();
    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
      statusCode: 200,
      message: 'Industrial Masterdata fetched successfully',
      data,
    });
```

While printing response object in interceptor i am not getting data. receiving correct content-length,status code in response object.

what am i missing:(

I want to encrypt only body while sending response to client.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling `res.send()` or any variant of it, then whatever you do in the `next.handle().pipe()` of the interceptor is irrelevant. The response is already sent. If you want to get the response body in the pipe, you need to return the data from the controller, and let Nest handle actually sending the response for you